# Extract text from delimited string into another delimited string TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this string, for example `Green/1051;Brown/1258;Red/1110;Yellow /1024;Red/1147;`

And I would like to be able to get the following string from this `1051;1258;1110;1024;1147;`

I have tried multiple solutions but they tend to cater to one 'part' of the string. If this isn't possible, then I can format this on the c# side, however it would be nice to be able to do this in my stored procedure.

Thanks

EDIT: Unfortunately this is a third party dataset so I have formatted this data using C#. From the answers below, I agree that SQL is not designed to be able to extract and parse what I need, it just would have been easier to maintain.

Comment: SQL, the language, isn't meant for string parsing. Why are you trying to parse this string in SQL in the first place? You can't take advantage of indexes or querying. If you used a format already supported by SQL Server, like XML or JSON, you could at least query the data

Comment: _I have tried multiple solutions_ --> Please add your code

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? If you need parts of that data, why store it as a string like this? And why have the *server* parse it? Do you want to use the results in other queries? The answer *matters a lot*. If you want to use the results in a larger query you should probably consider using a proper table design, eg with sparse columns or a separate related table. Another option could be to replace `/` and `;` with `"`" and `'` to make it look like JSON, to allow you to use `OPENJSON` to extract the values as a result set.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is a third party table with data not entered my me. Believe me, I know this is a very bad way of storing this data. If this is not possible I will just format this on the C# side.

Comment: @JackWaters you haven't explained what you want yet. Do you want to use the results in a query or not? If *not*, why bother parsing in the database? What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Does the order of numbers in the result need to match the original order?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: Is the string in question such that the problem can be generalized to removing all characters that aren't numbers or semicolons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume the reason the data needs to be parsed on the server is to use it in a larger query. Otherwise there's no reason to parse it on the server. It would be a lot easier to do so in C#, eg with a regex.

Without knowing which SQL Server, it is, I'll just assume it's 2016 or later, because that allows us to convert the string into a JSON value by replacing `\` with `":"` and `;` with `","`. A similar technique can be used in older versions to convert the string to XML.

Assuming this simple table :

```
declare @table table (id int identity primary key,col varchar(max))

insert into @table (col)
values ('Green/1051;Brown/1258;Red/1110;Yellow /1024;Red/1147;')
```

We can use `STUFF(col,len(col),1,'')` to delete the trailing semicolon. This query :

```
select stuff(col,len(col),1,'')
from @table
```

Gives

```
Green/1051;Brown/1258;Red/1110;Yellow /1024;Red/1147
```

Replacing `/` and `;` with

```
select replace(replace(stuff(col,len(col),1,''),'/','":"'),';','","')
from @table
```

Gives :

```
Green":"1051","Brown":"1258","Red":"1110","Yellow ":"1024","Red":"1147
```

We just need to complete the JSON string now by surrounding this value with `{"` and `"}`.

Once we do this we can use OPENJSON :

```
select *
from @table 
    cross apply openjson('{"' + replace(replace(stuff(col,len(col),1,''),'/','":"'),';','","') + '"}')
```

This will return the `id`, `col` columns from the source table and `key`, `value` and `type` columns from OPENJSON :

```
select id,[key],value
from @table 
    cross apply openjson('{"' + 
replace(replace(stuff(col,len(col),1,''),'/','":"'),';','","') + '"}') x
```

Will return :

```
id  key     value
1   Green   1051
1   Brown   1258
1   Red     1110
1   Yellow  1024
1   Red     1147
```

We can join those results with another table. Let's say those numbers are item IDs and we have an inventory table with the amounts in store for each one :

```
declare @inventory table (colorid int,amount int)

insert into @inventory (colorid,amount)
values
(1051,5),
(1258,10),
(1110,24),
(1024,2),
(1147,22)
```

Which items have an amount above 20?

```
select id, [key],colorid,amount
from @table 
    cross apply openjson('{"' + replace(replace(stuff(col,len(col),1,''),'/','":"'),';','","') + '"}') x
inner join @inventory i on i.colorid=x.value
where amount>20
```

The result is :

```
id  key colorid amount
1   Red 1110    24
1   Red 1147    22
```

Comment: Thanks for this. And yes it is SQL 2016

Answer (score 0):

Search for DelimitedSplit8K.
This will allow you to convert the string into a number of rows splitting on the ;

You can then use STUFF..FOR XML to rebuild the string

Alternatively, if you know that you will always want ALL of the numbers and semi-colons and NONE of the Alpha and spaces you could use

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(instring,[A-Z],''),' ','')
```

Comment: This isn't a useful answer. `DelimitedSplit8K` is just the name Aaron Bertrand gave to one of the techniques he was benchmarking. Telling someone to just search for the articles isn't very helpful. Furthermore, instead of splitting multiple times, the XML technique could be used to convert the string into a proper XML string with attributes that can be queried

Comment: What is the column `[A-Z]`? If it's meant to be a string `REPLACE` does not support pattern expressions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's actually the name Jeff Moden gave the [function](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function) he designed.

Comment: @Larnu I know, but I don't want to google for this. The answerer should have done this.

Comment: On that, I agree @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: My bad. You are right REPLACE does not support patterns.  I have been using PATINDEX and LIKE quite a bit in a recent project. however I disagree about the reference to DelimitedSplit8K.  In my experience this is one of the best tools written in SQL and although it may not be the most performant in all cases as per Betrram's tests it suffices in most scenarios.  I see no difference between referencing this by its name and recommending a javascript library, npm or python package by name - you wouldn't suggest someone rewrite the functionality of _lodash.

Comment: and by providing the link to Jeff's post you deprive the OP of the commentary and testing done by AB. plus what happens when the link dies..